# Binding image size with another image size

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm developing a Windows 8.1 store app with C# and .NET Framework 4.5.1.

```
<Border x:Name="Border00" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,10,10,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Canvas.ZIndex="1">
    <Image x:Name="Back00" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/BackCard/back.png"/>
</Border>
<Image x:Name="Front00" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,10,10,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Back00}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Back00}"/>
```

I'm trying to set `Front00` image size equal to `Back00` image size, but its height an its width is always zero, but `Back00` has this `height`: **Auto(239)**, and this `width`: **Auto(239)**.

I'm using this binding:

`Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=Back00}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Back00}"`

But it doesn't work.

**Any idea?**

Comment: any binding error in output window? How could you say "*it is always zero*"?

Comment: No, no errors. It's size it is always zero, but `Back00` has this height: Auto(239), and this widht: Auto(239).

Comment: try :Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=Back00}" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=Back00}"

Comment: @VansFannel Your XAML works fine for me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualheight), I have read this:

*For purposes of ElementName binding, ActualHeight does not post updates when it changes (due to its asynchronous and run-time calculated nature). Do not attempt to use ActualHeight as a binding source for an ElementName binding. If you have a scenario that requires updates based on ActualHeight, use a SizeChanged handler.*

So, I have added this on XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="Back00" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/BackCard/back.png" SizeChanged="Back00_SizeChanged"/>
```

And on Code Behind:

```
private void Back00_SizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Front00.Height = Back00.ActualHeight;
    Front00.Width = Back00.ActualWidth;
}
```

And now it works perfectly.